# Borel-Cantelli Application

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that the set of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which there exists infinitely many $\frac{p}{q}, (p,q)=1$ such that $|x-\frac{p}{q}|\leq \frac{1}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$ has measure $0$. The approach I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641159/if-x-notin-mathbbq-then-leftx-fracpq-right-frac1q2-epsilon) used an enumeration of rationals $\{\frac{p_k}{q_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and defined $E_k = \{x\in\mathbb{R} : |x-\frac{p_k}{q_k}|\le \frac{1}{q_{k}^{2+\epsilon}}\}$ and claimed that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m(E_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{q_k^{2+\epsilon}}<\infty$. However, I am not sure that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{q_k^{2+\epsilon}}<\infty$ because some $q_{k}$ can be repeated infinitely often in the enumeration on the rationals. I understand that if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{q_k^{2+\epsilon}}<\infty$, we can use the borel cantelli lemma, but I am not quite clear why that is the case.

Comment: wlog $x \in [0,1]$. then only need to consider rationals $\frac{p_k}{q_k}$ with $q_k \ge 1$ and $0 \le p_k \le q_k$. so each $q_k$ occurs at most $q_k+1$ times, so we basically get $\sum \frac{1}{q_k^{1+\epsilon}}$, convergent.

Comment: Why do we only need to consider $x \in [0,1]$

Comment: it suffices to show that, for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the set of $x$ in $[k,k+1]$ for which there exist infinitely many such $\frac{p}{q}$ has measure $0$ (since countable union of measure 0 sets has measure 0). but $[0,1]$, for this problem, is the same as any $[k,k+1]$.